# Selecting an element after another without following axis in XPath

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping

I have the following tree snippet:

```
<div class="pagesection">
  <div class="pagelinks floatleft">Pagine: [<strong>1</strong>]
    <a class="navPages" href="http://foo.com/2">2</a>
    <a class="navPages" href="http://foo.com/3">3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the navigation pane of a section of a website I need to scrap. So, I need to access the first A link (the next page) after the strong element (the current page).

I cannot use `//DIV[@class="pagelinks"]/A[1]` because when I'm for ex. on page 2, the first link of the pane is the 1st page. This would cause a loop in my scraper (it expects a "next page" link resulting from the expression). To be sure of navigating forward I must access the A link **after** the current page only.

Even worst, the scraper doesn't allow the use of preceding/following axis, but preceding-siblings and following-siblings seems to be supported, instead.

Which xpath expression I've to use for access that A link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first `following-sibling::a`:

```
//div[contains(@class, "pagelinks")]/strong/following-sibling::a[1]/text()
```

Demo (using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) tool):

```
$ xmllint index.html --xpath '//div[contains(@class, "pagelinks")]/strong/following-sibling::a[1]/text()'
2
```

Comment: tnx! it works perfectly (i had just to make a small changes as contains() is not supported)!